# How to pass a function as an parameter to a contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm trying to make a dynamic rule builder in solidity, I have a role manager contract that looks like so:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


// The Ownable contract to manage the contract owner
contract RoleManager is Ownable {

    mapping(bytes32 => function(bytes32, address, address[] memory, uint256[] memory, bytes[] memory, string memory) external view returns (bool)) public rules;

    // Set the rule for the given role
    function setRule(bytes32 role, function(bytes32, address, address[] memory, uint256[] memory, bytes[] memory, string memory) external view returns (bool) rule) public onlyOwner {
        rules[role] = rule;
    }

   //...
}
```

Maybe my understanding of what `function` parameter is wrong, I would like to build a dynamic function, How to I generate a function on ethers to pass to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use interface :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

interface IRule {
    function rule (bytes32 data, address addr, 
       address[] memory addrArr, uint256[] memory uintArr, 
       bytes[] memory dataArr, string memory str)
    external view returns (bool);
}
contract Demo is Ownable {
    mapping(bytes32 => IRule)  public rules;
    function setRule(bytes32 role, IRule rule) public onlyOwner {
        rules[role] = rule;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I'm trying to dynamically build rules, not have to deploy them first

Comment: It seems that you want to execute dynamic code. Maybe this post could help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/function-to-execute-raw-bytecode-in-evm

Comment: Interesting it is possible, they just don't show how, I'll try to resolve it